# Manipulate single form from many different projects

Tags: c#, forms, plugins

I have created a plugin-framework. it's pretty simple, reads a file for all 'dlls' then loads them into my program.

I am trying to have a single Windows Form that can be freely manipulated by every plugin.

How can I have all of my separate projects (every plugin is in a different project) modify this control dynamically, but still remain in separate projects?

Comment: Put the form in a seperate dll and add a nice interface and then use it from the plug-ins?

Comment: Yeah, can you expand on that a bit please? I guess I don't fully understand how I should do that.

Comment: infer-On seems to have covered the basics. essentially we are talking about sharing a concrete form, or better still injecting a concrete form which implements a shared interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems a little broad(*how do you load the plugins? What operations plugins do on target Form?*), anyway the simplest answer should tell you to put a reference to an *IContainerControl*/*Form* in your plugins, so that you can inject the reference to your *Form* instance in the plugins

But heavily depend to your implementation system, I think if you target Form implement a common interface, your plugins could easily work on interface reference